# JSTL object inside html:option

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, struts

I want to create a dropbox which includes numbers from 00 to 59.

On the web page, it works fine, it is displayed just like I want, but when I get minutes element from form by `getMinutes()` I get the string `"${i.id}"` instead of the desired number.

Here's my code:

```jsp
<html:select property="minutes">
  <c:forEach var="i" begin="0"  end="59" step="1">
     <c:if test="${ i < 10 }">
        <html:option value="${i}"><c:out value="0${i}"  /></html:option>
     </c:if>
     <c:if test="${ i >= 10 }">
        <html:option value="${i}"><c:out value="${i}" /></html:option>
     </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
</html:select>
```

I have tried the code below too, but it doesn't work either.

```jsp
 <html:option value='<c:out value="${i}" />'></html:option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine if you have getter and setter for the property `minutes` on the action form

```
public Long getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

public void setMinutes(Long minutes) {
    this.minutes= minutes;
}
```

It should work with the integer type too.